# Cloud Firestore Data modelling

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firestore and I am designing a demo application where each users can share a task and others can do the task. Here is the idea.
Let's say I have 3 users.

- User 1 uploads a task (task 1)
- Both user 2 and user 3 can see the task (task 1)
- User 2 completes the task (task 1)
- Only user 3 can now see and read that task document. User 2 can not
  read the document because he already completed the task

Each task can be deleted in the future.
Each task can be completed a limited number of times (lets say task 1 can only be completed 10 times and would be deleted afterward).

My first plan was to keep an array of elements (user ID) in each of the task documents and query for documents by 'array-does-not-contain' however this seemed impossible as firestore works by indexing and it is not possible to index data that does not exist.

So my second plan was to do the reverse way - keep an array of taskID in the user document and search by using 'where-not-in' however this also has a limit of only 10 element in the search array. So, I had to give this idea up as well.

I am currently thinikng of getting 20 documents per read and check them locally however, this can increase document reads as you might expect.

Any idea how I can model the data so that user can query only those document (tasks) that he/she hasn't completed yet?

Comment: Another approach might be to store the task under each user document in a sub collection (eg. `tasks`). That way the task is isolated and only relevant to that particular user. Once the user completes the task you can delete the document or create a field like `complete: true`. This will also let you apply security rules and lock document(task) access to a user.

Comment: You would just need to come up with a solution to propagate the new task to all the users that needed to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

you can definitely get away with doing some relational like things in Firestre however it seems as though your use case is exceeding the capability and purpose of Firestore.

**Option 1:** Create a solution to push new tasks to a sub-collection (eg. Tasks) under each user that needs to complete it. This will then allow you to use database security rules to protect that task from other users and also allow easy querying from a user perspective. **The problem with this** though is you will now have duplicate copies of the same task and you'll need a way to track the task status across all the users (if that's applicable). Otherwise there's no way to see which users have completed that task.

```
#Task example
id: 123123123 <-- must be the same so you can find it across all users
text: Do XYZ
user_id: 123abc <-- some sort of reference to the user
complete: false/true
```

[image: option 1]

**Option 2:** Move to a relational database so you can do this much easier. You would have a table of tasks, a table of users, and then a task_user table that tracks each user to a task. **The problem with this** is that working with SQL DBs is a bit more work and not as streamline as getting started with Firestore.

[image: option 2]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a top level collection named "tasks" and add a document for each task. You should store an array of UIDs of users who can access that task. So a sample document may look like this:

```
{
  addedBy: "uid_of_creator",
  users: ["uid1", "uid_of_creator", "uid36"]
  addedAt: 1626243188399,
  ...otherDocFields
}
```

You can use the following query to list the tasks a user has access to:

```
const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

firebase.firestore().collection("tasks").where("users", "array-contains", userId).get().then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.empty) {
    // No tasks
  } else {
    const tasks = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
    console.log(tasks)
  }
})
```

Do note that I've used `array-contains` operator and not `array-contains-any`. So you don't have to about the 10 equality clauses limit.

You must set the security rules so that a user can access their own tasks:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /tasks/{taskID} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
    }
  }
}
```

Pros of using this method would be you are not replicating the tasks for all users and you can easily control permissions using security rules.